# Blue-tooth scanning issue if multiple BT devices are available

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, network-scan

Now many lights at home can be controlled by blue-tooth, as you know LBT technology on iOS supports it very well.

But one question is that if there are four rooms available (very near) and each blue-tooth supported light for each room, then during BT service scanning, how to match the device and service?

Is it determined by signal strength? Or do we need to set its name during first connection?  Any other great solution?

Anyone who are interested please share, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Mostly RSSI, it's not accurate, but still. Plus, often, you can rename your object (a characteristic implemented), so you can add an "assurance" that the right device.

Comment: Good idea. You mean once got after scanning, then set its characteristic name, next time scan by new name, am I right?  Of course the device name characteristic should be writable.

Comment: Yes. My colleague created a characteristic (writable) to rename it. Another solution he used at start, was to create a name with a part of a MAC Address, to make it more identifiable like: "MyObjectName 0D5F", which is quite useful either you can rename it or not.

Comment: Good suggestion, a nice solution so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know which peripheral is the nearest, we may say to we'll use RSSI.
It's a great way to know if they are near of far, BUT it's not accurate. Put a wall between your device and your peripheral, and its distance may seems farer. Let's say it's a tip, by not a real indication. Plus, let's say you are exactly at the same distance between two peripheral (so imagine same RSSI given). Which one is which one?

If the firmware allows it, you may rename your device (a writable characteristic). So in your example, let's say we rename your devices with: *Light Living Room*, *Light Garage*, *Light Kitchen*, etc. So it may help you to identify them when you want to connect. But, that works only if you already connected to them, and only if you can rename them.

If you also work with the firmware side, a good start, could be to name them with a part of a unique word. A solution, could be to name them like this: *MainName XxX*, where *XxX* could be for example, the last 4 hex of the communication cheap MAC Address. Of course, you may encounter the time where you find 2 identical XxX, but let's say it's quite rare.
 
Note, that could also work for Wi-Fi devices. We had a Wi-Fi toy that generates a Wi-Fi network with it's "ProductName XxXx", where XxXx where "unique" (Wi-Fi Chip MAC Address).
Also note, that on the peripheral part, they may have access to their "real" MAC Address, whereas in iOS, it's a mix between a timestamp, a MAC Address of the device/peripheral, and so may be change afterward (every 15 minutes I think), unless you paired with them. So it may be used and not used between 2 iOS devices.

Comment: Thanks you guys. Good solution, I will try your idea on my project.

Comment: I don;t understand how to rename the device while scanning different device but all are not connected ...

Comment: You have to rename them once you've connected to them, IF and only if the device allows it.